# How to convert a list to a dictionary python; is having more than one value to a key possible for a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
import csv

ratings_file = open("ratings.txt","r")
book_file = open("booklist.txt","r")
ratinglist = open("ratings.txt").readlines()
booklist = open("booklist.txt").readlines()

print(ratinglist)
```

Here is the list that I have right now:

```
['Ben\n', '5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 \n', 'Moose\n', '5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0 \n', 'Reuven\n', '5 -5 0 0 0 0 -3 -5 0 1 -5 5 0 1 0 1 -3 1 -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 -5 1 0 1 0 -5 0 3 -3 3 0 1 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 1 5 1 3 \n'
```

What I need to do is convert it to a dictionary.

I would like the dictionary to be set up along the lines of this:

```
{"Ben" [5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 ], "Moose" [5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0]}
```

For every persons name. The issue is that theyre are more keys to a single value, and im wondering if this is possible using python. I have read online that it is, but the syntax for it is confusing, or that it is not possible at all.

Is what im trying to do possible?

Comment: Sure, just loop over each pair and add it to a dictionary.

Comment: Are you saying that a person's name appears more than once in your list?

Comment: no, but i thought dictionaries can only have one key and one value. Like Ben could only have one value for 1

Comment: Sure, but your value can be a list.

Comment: oh, i did not know that you can make your value a list. So in essence you can have a value that is a list inside of a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the entire file into memory at once, iterate line by line with a `for` loop, but *also* read a line explicitly using `next` in the body of the loop. This effectively lets you iterate two lines at a time; we'll assume that there is an even number of lines in the file, to avoid having to catch `StopIteration` explicitly, though that can be added easily if needed.

```
d = {}

with open("ratings.txt") as f:
    for name in f:
        ratings = next(f)
        d[name.strip()] = [int(x) for x in ratings.strip().split()]
```

Note that you must use `next(f)`, not `f.readline()`, in the body, because the iterator may be doing its own buffering of data read from the file, and the line you think `f.readline()` would return may have already been read by the iterator, and is sitting in memory waiting for a future call to `next` to return it.

Comment: Is this a common idiom? I like it but I've never seen anyone use it before.

Comment: Not terribly common. I'll just note that you do need to use `next` in the body, rather than using `f.readline()`, because the file iterator may be doing its own buffering; the string you think `f.readline()` will return may have already been read by the iterator and is sitting in memory waiting to be returned by a future call to `next`.

Answer (score -1):

To convert a string of ratings into a list of `int`s:

```
def parse_ratings(s):
    return [int(x) for x in s.strip().split()]
```

To put your `rating_list` inside a dictionary simply loop through in steps of 2:

```
def rating_list_to_dict(rating_list):
    d = {}
    for i in range(0, len(rating_list) // 2, 2):
        name = rating_list[i]
        ratings = parse_ratings(rating_list[i + 1])
        d[name] = ratings
    return d
```